# How could I get a layout like the one shown in the attached image?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-float

I'm relatively new to HTML/CSS, and I'm trying to figure out how best to achieve a layout similar to this:

[image]

The layout would display the number of people a user is following and being followed by (these would be links). The 1st and 2nd stats would be followed by a right margin (to help divide the content)

Any tips?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple hash of it

http://jsfiddle.net/H5BVs/

Shoudl point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a mill guys. So I could just add a <a href="" class=""> to each li in Xavier's solution or to each div in either Graeme or Jason's solution to link them to corresponding pages?

Answer (score 1):

here you can view a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2LxxT/

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>3</span>
        followers
    </li>
    <li class="padded">
        <span>6</span>
        following
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>2</span>
        props
    </li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
ul
{ font-family: arial; }

/* LI's have a default display of block, setting a float will display them on the same line, alternatively display:inline-block; would do the same */
    ul li
    {float:left;height:60px; font-size: 12px; color: #A19AA2; }

/* Target the very first list element */
    ul li:first-child
    { padding-right: 20px; }

/* Target the very last list element */
    ul li:last-child
    { padding-left: 20px; }

/* Add padding to your middle element */
    ul li.padded
    { border-left: 1px solid #E8E8E8; border-right: 1px solid #E8E8E8; padding:0 20px; }

/* Change your span from an inline element to a block element */
    ul li span
    { display: block; font-size: 20px; color: #434343; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 12px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

**HTML**

```
<div id="followers"><span>3</span>followers</div>
<div id="following"><span>3</span>following</div>
<div id="props"><span>2</span>props</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#followers, #following, #props{
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;
    text-align:center;
}

#props{
    border:none;
}

#followers span, #following span, #props span{
    font-size:1.8em;
    display:block;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PxDMa/